# Why isn't it working when I attempt to open a firefox browser using rSelenium?

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I am new to R and am trying to web scrape a jsp page to collect data. The page I want scrape from is: https://www.taxpayerservicecenter.com/RP_Search.jsp After I get a browser to open this url, I want to select neighborhoods, and scrape all the data there.

**Also, is there an easier/better way to do this?** This page has buttons and forms so it isn't as straight forward as say, scraping from a wikipedia page.

```
library(RSelenium) #passes
checkForServer() #passes 
startServer() #passes 
remDriver <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr="localhost", port=4444, browserName="firefox")
```

The following line is where I receive the error:

```
remDriver$open() #opens a browser, get the farthest w firefox
```

This is the error message I receive. I have searched everywhere for how to solve this!:

```
> remDriver$open() #opens a browser, get the farthest w firefox
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException
```

Things I have tried:

- connecting to selenium server standalone by searching it and clicking on it
- running the following: checkForServer(update = TRUE)

Here is my Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RSelenium_1.3.5 XML_3.98-1.4    RJSONIO_1.3-0   RCurl_1.95-4.8  bitops_1.0-6   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0    caTools_1.17.1
```

Please, please, help!

Comment: I was able to run your code on a similar machine with no issue and my guess is it might be a java issue. can you load rJava with error?

Comment: This is likely an issue with an update to the Selenium download page see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578885/rselenium-not-working-with-firefox